# TexLive2022: on-the-fly package installation stops working

Tags: packages, linuxfedora, texlive2022

I just upgraded my **Fedora** release from **37** to **38** which in turn upgraded my
texlive release to **TeXLive2022**. This upgrade remvoed all my previously downloaded
Tex packages. This could be just an undisirable side effect but when I process my Tex
files the *on-the-fly installation* of the missing packages doesn't work as in previous release.

I get the message as if the `packagename.sty` is nt found. It seems that the **lualatex** & **pdflatex** both expect all the packages to be found already in the installation directory.

So I have to install the missing packages by hand through:

`sudo dnf install 'tex(lettrine.sty)' 'tex(anotherOne.sty)'`

@ulrike-fischer talked ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132951/package-files-not-downloading-on-an-account-without-privileges)) about the download timeout due to the network low speed. I admit that my internet is slow but it was fast enough for the previous texlive version. The timeout value might have been changed, but the error message is silent on this.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just a note: Ulrike's comment was about MiKTeX. You say, you are using TeX Live packages of fedora linux. BTW: Until your question, it was news to me that fedora linux supports on-the-fly installation of packages with TeX Live. Instead I would try `sudo dnf install texlive-full` to get all of TeX Live installed or I would use a Vanilla TeX Live installation, which is by default also a full installation and which would be an up-to-date TeX Live 2023.

Comment: @cabohah I've been using TexLive on Fedora for years and the on-the-fly package istallation has been always working. I've got loads of documents using this.
As to your suggestion about installing the FULL beast, I avoid to do it. I tried the extra package installation (texlive-scheme-full). It solved the problem but it's too big (about 5GB) on the top of texlive itself (huge too), all sitting on the / partition. When you have to deploy these on a cloud server, size matters. The optimal solution is the *on-the-fly installation* one.

Comment: upstream texlive does not have on the fly installation, can you link to the documentation of that fedora feature?